# Error after ng build command run "entry not found"

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli

I build my project with command "ng build --prod" or "ng build --prod --base-href ./" and works fine also run project on webserver and works fine too but when i press F5 i recieve next error 
[image]

i have angular cli version 
[image]

and my package.json

```
{
  "name": "ConceptPeluqueria",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": "ConceptPeluqeria",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "maxbuild": "ng build --prod",
    "build": "ng build --prod --base-href ./",
    "gitbuild": "ng build --prod --base-href /start-angular/SB-Admin-BS4-Angular-6/master/dist/",
    "test": "ng test",
    "test-ci": "TEST_CI=true ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "subirtodo": "git add . & git commit -m \"Commit automatico\" & git push origin master",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^2.2.2",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^10.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.2",
    "core-js": "^2.5.5",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "ng2-charts": "^1.6.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.1.0",
    "yarn": "^1.6.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "6.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^9.6.1",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.1.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.0.0",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.7.0",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.0"
  }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Probably because you are using `./`

Comment: Thanks Robin but no, i ran it too without "/" and had the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

This is a common problem with people who are new to hosting a Single-Page Application (SPA). The issue is that the entire Angular app gets run off of a single route, in your case `127.0.0.1:8887/`, all routes that exist in the Angular app, i.e. `/dashboard`, aren't routes that the server knows about. This is why if you enter at the root, the entire app will work fine but if you go to a sub-route like `127.0.0.1:8887/dashboard` it falls over because the web server has nothing bound to that route.

Long story short, you need to use a server that, when it gets any any 404 routing errors, should serve the `index.html` file. If you do a Google search for 'how to serve SPA application`, there are tons of options and your own server may even be capable of it.